# How to change HTB rate of a classid?

Tags: tc, htb

I have tc htb qdisc setup that looks like

```
     1:0
      |
     1:1
    /   \
 1:10   1:11
```

---

```
# tc -s -d class show dev br0
```

Shows class 1:10 with 1024kbit rate and ceil:

```
class htb 1:10 parent 1:1 prio quantum rate 1024Kbit ceil 1024Kbit linklayer ethernet burst 15Kb/1 mpu 0b cburst 1599b/1 mpu 0b level 0 
 Sent 3271331 bytes 3482 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 2132 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
 lended: 3482 borrowed: 0 giants: 0
 tokens: 1866943 ctokens: 187255
```

I want to change to rate/ceil of class 1:10. What I tried:

```
# tc class change dev br0 classid 1:10 rate 1kbit
```

And

```
# tc class change dev br0 parent 1:0 classid 1:10 rate 1kbit prio 1
```

I can't find any example in the internet that uses the change command of tc. I remember there was an example somewhere in the lartc documentations, but I can't find it anymore. [TC man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc.8.html) says it has the same command syntax as add, but I couldn't make it work. The error says:

```
 Error: Qdisc "rate" is classless.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could try something like this:

```
 sudo tc class change dev br0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 1kbit ceil 5kbit burst 16b
```

Comment: Yes. Actually, the man page is right. Change command has the same syntax as the add command. I didn't know why my previous attempt didn't work. Perhaps it was lacking the parent id.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the class and adding a new class definition with the same class id

```
#tc class del dev br0 classid 1:10
#tc class add dev br0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 rate 1kbit
```